# JS show hide feild diappear when clicking submit

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php form which has a dropdown list and a text which show and hide based on drop down list value. The problem is when I click submit button and there is validation error the onload function work and the text hide ,,, it should stay visible or invisible depending on the drop down list.

Here is what Im doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showfield(name){
    if(name != 'High School')
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
    else 
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
  }

  function hidefield() {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
 }
<script>
```

Im calling the hidefield function here on body on load:

```
<body onload = "hidefield()">
```

and the other function on the drop downlist

```
<select name="education" size="1" class="text" id="education" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

Hope some one can help.

Comment: Any idea how I can solve this ? still not working as I want

Answer (score 0):

just modify your hidefield function to only hide it if it needs to

```
function hidefield() {
    var select = document.getElementById("education");
    if (select.options[select.selectedIndex] != 'High School')
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: I modified the hide function but still same thing happen,,, the text box hide when I clich submit

Answer (score 0):

Script is missing the closing tag,

```
 </script> after the function hidefield()
```

Comment: the closing tag was missed here only ,,, still waiting to solve it